# how to display images?

Tags: python, django

please help bring images into the template

in django1.6 I uploaded via the form in the database image. [screenshot](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/kk.png). ( checked that the images loaded in a specific directory ) . then imported into the template file settings.py variable BASE_DIR and to all records of a table . then tried in the template to display the image as follows:

```
{% for entrie in all_entries_carousel %}
        <a href="{{ entrie.link }}" title="{{ entrie.title }}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{{ BASE_DIR }}/{{ entrie.image }}" width="300" height="200" alt="{{ entrie.title }}" />
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

results in images that I have not loaded and displayed.
in the source path

```
c:\Python33\django_projects\proj1/carousel/media/images/img1.png
```

please tell me how can I still display the image. Sure , there is a path without importing BASE_DIR

ps this way does not work `proj1/carousel/media/images/img1.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your static files.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

1. Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your
   `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
3. In your templates, either hardcode the url like
   /static/my_app/myexample.jpg or, preferably, use the static template
   tag to build the URL for the given relative path by using the
   configured STATICFILES_STORAGE storage (this makes it much easier
   when you want to switch to a content delivery network (CDN) for
   serving static files).

   `{% load staticfiles %}
   <img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>`
4. Store your static files in a folder called `static` in your app. For
   example `my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg`.